# Using same scope for multiple models

Tags: php, laravel

How would I create a scope that can be used by multiple models without polluting the global scope space? This scope would be manually called each time I want to use it.

Example:

```
$assigns = Assign::dryScope();
$contacts = Contact::dryScope();
```

Comment: That's the only way, global scopes. You may want to play with `Traits`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way is to use traits. Use appropriate namespacing as needed.
ScopeTrait.php

```
trait ScopeTrait {
   protected function dryScope() {
    //Scope definition
    }
}


class Assign extends xModel
{
    use ScopeTrait;

}
```

Comment: Used a trait. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that extends the Model, follows a template below:

```
class xModel extends Model
{

    protected function dryScope() {}

}


class Assign extends xModel
{

}
```